# Limiting decimal places in data imported as .CSV and joined to shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, csv, decimal-points

I am importing a csv into QGIS 2.4 with a csvt file that specifies for percent columns Real(2.1) to limit it to 1 decimal place. It imports fine. When I join it to a shapefile, it looks fine. But when I save the shapefile with a new name and bring it back in (or use it in another program), all the numbers have about 10 decimal places. The extra 0s don't show, but some wind up as xx.x99999999999.

Is there a way of limiting the number of decimal places in those columns to just 1?

Comment: Floating points are by definition imprecise, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format. The best you can hope for is altering the display characteristics of the table to round to 1 decimal place see http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html